# Unpivoting Data from Spreadsheet into Data Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, import

Here is a bit of background just in case there is a different/better way of solving my problem.

I have a query that I've exported from Access to a spreadsheet.  The exported data was a pivot query export which I passed it off to another worker who has updated the table and passed it back to me.  Also, the underlying data is actually a linked table from SQL 2005.  I'm mentioning that because I'm not afraid to us SQL Server to update this data, but since the export originated from Access, I assumed it would be best to update it from their.

This is the basics of what the table data and export was structured like:  I

```
Data Table
==========
PK_1      PK_2      VALUE
------------------------------
G1        SG1       .33
G1        SG2       .44
...
G2        SG1       .33
G2        SG2       .44
...
G3        SG1       .33
G3        SG2       .44
...
```

..and this is what the exported data looked like in Excel.

```
Pivot Data Exported to Excel
============================

          G1        G2       ...
SG1       .33       .33      ...
SG2       .44       .44      ...
SG3       .55       .55      ...
...       ...       ...      ...
```

My question is how can I unpivot the updated spreadsheet data into my data table that needs to be updated? Is there an unpivot operation in Access, possibly as part of an importation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access does not have an UNPIVOT but you can do this via multiple UNION queries

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=204468

[How to convert fields into rows through SQL in MS Access 2007 or MS SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334571/how-to-convert-fields-into-rows-through-sql-in-ms-access-2007-or-ms-sql-server-20)

here is an example with your data:

```
SELECT PK_2, "G1" as "PK_1", G1 as [Value]
FROM Table
UNION
SELECT PK_2, "G2" as "PK_1", G2 as [Value]
FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple response.  I was somewhat aware of both of your answers, however, I wasn't sure if there was another means of achieving this goal.  I think my best option is to go with the first.