# Reading crosstab numbers from excel to access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have to load a bunch of numbers from excel to access. I used [Import Excel data in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866255/import-excel-data-in-access) to load the data earlier.

Earlier :-

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 QTY
A1     B1     C1      1
A1     B2     C2      2
A1     B3     C3      3
A1     B4     C4      4
A1     B5     C5      5
```

My data is in a crosstab format now. 
For example :-

```
A1  B1  B2 B3 B4 B5
C1  1   0  0  0  0
C2  0   2  0  0  0
C3  0   0  3  0  0
C4  0   0  0  4  0
C5  0   0  0  0  5
```

Is there a direct way in which I can import this to access? Or do I have to use a macro to convert into the linear form used earlier.

Thanks,
Arka.

Comment: I'm not sure how it became a cross-tab format.  Using the link you gave, and creating the target table ahead of time with Field1, Field2, Field3, and Qty, I get exactly the data in the spreadsheet in the table.  Could you add more detail to your post?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the really late comment. Actually it did not become crosstab. My data is in crosstab. I used to implement a macro to convert it into normal form.

Comment: Oh, so the data in Excel is in a crosstab, and you want to import it into Access, looking like the first table in your post.  Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly! Right now the data-set is quite huge, hence the macro takes some time to copy-paste it into the first format.

Comment: Not familiar with a quick way to do this, but I found this searching for UNPIVOT ms-access:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/334611/195613  which reads
No need to export to SQL Server. In Access, try the /View/PivotTable View submenu. (It's in my Access 2003, at any rate.) I like it better than the one in Excel.